# wsdl php : Undefined property: stdClass

Tags: php, wsdl

I try to create a web service in PHP (and use it in C# application).
I wrote lot of post but I can't find my mistake.

when I test this code, properties of my class `Client` are unknow 
(`error => Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Nom in C:\wamp\www\webservice\index.php on line 8`)

could you help me ?

**Here Client.wsdl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://localhost/webservice/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" targetNamespace="http://localhost/webservice/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://localhost/webservice/">
      <s:element name="GetClient">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="id" type="s:int" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetClientResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetClientResult" type="tns:Client" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="Client">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Id" type="s:int" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Nom" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Prenom" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="GetClientSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetClient" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetClientSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetClientResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ConvertirSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetClient">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetClientSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetClientSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="ConvertirSoap" type="tns:ConvertirSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetClient">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://localhost/webservice/GetClient" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="ConvertirSoap12" type="tns:ConvertirSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetClient">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://localhost/webservice/GetClient" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="Convertir">
    <wsdl:port name="ConvertirSoap" binding="tns:ConvertirSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost/webservice/client.php" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="ConvertirSoap12" binding="tns:ConvertirSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://localhost/webservice/client.php" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**Here Client.php**

```
<?php

class Client {

    public $Id;
    public $Nom;
    public $Prenom;

    function __construct($id, $nom, $prenom)
    {
        $this->Id = $id;
        $this->Nom = $nom;
        $this->Prenom = $prenom;
    }

    function GetClient($id)
    {
        $c = new Client($id, 'Jean', 'DUPONT');
        return $c;
    }
}

ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
$serversoap=new SoapServer("http://localhost/webservice/Client.wsdl");
$serversoap->setClass("Client");
$serversoap->handle();

?>
```

**Here my script test**

```
<?php
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);

$service=new SoapClient("http://localhost/webservice/Client.wsdl");

$result = $service->GetClient(5);

echo $result->Nom." ".$result->Prenom;
```

Comment: I've just delete "ConvertirSoap12" déclaration. Now my error is "Too few arguments to function Client::__construct(), 0 passed and exactly 3 expected"

Answer (score 0):

The error is here on your script

```
$service=new SoapClient("http://localhost/webservice/Client.wsdl");
```

replace this line with

```
$service= new Client("http://localhost/webservice/Client.wsdl", "", "");
```

When you are going to create an instance of any class you have to use that class name where you are using the wrong class name that doesn't exist. Another thing if there is a method that takes arguments then you have to give the values for all the arguments or you can define the argument default value as its definition. In your __construct() method you define three arguments but when you create an instance you gave only one value that is not  perfect. Rather than you can use `__construct($id = '', $nom = '', $prenom = '')` so whenever you do not put the other value if will work perfectly.

Comment: I do not agree with your answer.
My but in the test script is to call the serviceWeb and not the "client" class